# How do I replace a block of text with another block of text in elisp?

Tags: org-mode, replace

I'm working with an org-mode file that might contain headlines and text, like

```
* Headline 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: h1
  :END:
  This is some text.
** Subheading A
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: s1
   :END:
   The subheading can also have text.
```

Suppose I have a string bound to the symbol `mytext` that looks like

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: h1
:END:
This is some UPDATED text.

As you can see, it can
be multlined.
```

I want to replace h1's "body" text with the stuff in `mytext` (including the Properties drawer and all), but leave any subtrees alone. So the end result should look like

```
* Headline 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: h1
  :END:
  This is some UPDATED text.

  As you can see, it can
  be multlined.
** Subheading A
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: s1
   :END:
   The subheading can also have text.
```

What's the fastest / easiest way to do this with elisp?

Comment: `delete-region` and `insert` your symbol/text.  There are insufficient details in the question be more specific as we do not know how it is that the region to be replaced will be selected/chosen, where the cursor is in the buffer, whether the region is presently selected/highlighted, whether the original poster is looking for a select region consisting of the subtree in relation to wherever the cursor is presently located, etc.

Comment: The original poster may also be interested in `org-cut-subtree`:  "*Cut the current subtree into the clipboard.  With prefix arg N, cut this many sequential subtrees.  This is a short-hand for marking the subtree and then cutting it.*"

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [org-parser library](https://bitbucket.org/zck/org-parser.el) to pull the org file as a data structure, then make the changes, then write back to the org file:

```
(let* ((parsed-buffer (org-parser-parse-buffer "test.org"))
       (block-to-change (first parsed-buffer))
       (mytext ":PROPERTIES:
:ID: h1
:END:
This is some UPDATED text.

As you can see, it can
be multlined.")
       (mytext-as-org-block (concat "* title to be ignored\n" mytext))
       (new-properties (org-parser--get-properties mytext-as-org-block))
       (new-body (org-parser--get-body mytext-as-org-block)))
  (puthash :properties new-properties block-to-change)
  (puthash :body new-body block-to-change)
  (with-current-buffer "test.org"
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert (org-parser--to-string parsed-buffer))))
```

You obviously won't need to include `mytext` as part of the `let*`, and in fact, if you have the properties block as an alist (`'(("ID" . "h1"))`) separate from the body text, you can skip the `mytext-as-org-block`, and jump directly to the `puthash` lines.

Comment: What advantages does your library have over Org mode's parser, `org-element-parse-buffer`?

Comment: It more abstracts away the underlying file into a data structure, without reference back to the original string, nor extra attributes (why does each list from `#'org-element-parse-buffer` have `org-data nil` at the beginning of it?). This data structure is far more intuitive to work with. (Compare a plain list with only two items with both `#'org-element-parse-buffer` and `#org-parser-parse-buffer`).

Answer (score 0):

This plain replace-regexp seems to cut it:

```lisp
(defun org-replace-h1 ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((mytext "
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: h1
  :END:
  This is some UPDATED text.

  As you can see, it can
  be multlined."))

    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "^\\* \\(.+\\)\n\\(.+\\|\n\\)+?\\*" nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "* " (match-string 1) mytext "\n*") t nil))))
```